# Reference for the initial guess of BFGS

Tags: optimization

I've use $$\frac{y^Ts}{y^ty}I$$ for the initial guess in the BFGS. Now I've been looking for the reference for this guess. Can someone tell me which reference does this comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In section of L-BFGS, Numerical Optimization from Jorge Npcedal, you can find what you want. Best